# Need help deleting extra files from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

Hey guys I need either a SQL query or a script in order to delete all the images from my media library in Wordpress, except the ones that they have '320x180' as a resolution (or in their name)

The reason why is I have more than 100k files and I can't delete the manually as this would take centuries. SQL/programming is not my strongest point either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can easily delete files using "find" command on linux, just needed to do the same thing. Try this in the bash console:

```
cd /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
find -type f -regex '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.\(jpg\|png\|jpeg\)$' -delete
```

The above will delete all resized image versions leaving just the original uploads.

Comment: Used this on a Windows machine in Git Bash, worked perfectly, thanks!